# Shell script to push kube status to an api

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

Hi am srinivasa I need to write a script to push kubernetes status to an api there i need to grep only some columns after that i need to convert that output into json next i need to push that json output into my api please help me for this to write a script am a begginer to the scripting

my kubectl get pods output is

```
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
prometheus-alertmanager-df7d48c78-ctv52          2/2     Running   0          83d
prometheus-kube-state-metrics-6cd8cdc7b7-qx9n5   1/1     Running   0          83d
prometheus-node-exporter-ld56h                   1/1     Running   0          83d
prometheus-node-exporter-prtlw                   1/1     Running   0          83d
prometheus-node-exporter-rbgff                   1/1     Running   0          83d
prometheus-node-exporter-z9rvs                   1/1     Running   0          83d
prometheus-pushgateway-655f59475-fjrrf           1/1     Running   0          83d
prometheus-server-577d8b886-gn5qg                2/2     Running   0          83d
```

in this i need to grep only name ready and status columns only i didt find exact filter options please help me for this

Comment: Where is your script?

Comment: in this case, for print ready and status columns only, you can use awk, like: kubectl get pods |awk '{print $2" "$3}'

Comment: am getting output like this ```NAME READY STATUS
prometheus-alertmanager-df7d48c78-ctv52 2/2 Running
prometheus-kube-state-metrics-6cd8cdc7b7-qx9n5 1/1 Running
prometheus-node-exporter-ld56h 1/1 Running
prometheus-node-exporter-prtlw 1/1 Running
prometheus-node-exporter-rbgff 1/1 Running
prometheus-node-exporter-z9rvs 1/1 Running
prometheus-pushgateway-655f59475-fjrrf 1/1 Running
prometheus-server-577d8b886-gn5qg 2/2 Running
```

Comment: i cant find perfect filter options because i need to convert this outpot into json their am getting output total pod description i dont need that i need to get json output like this```[{
 "name": "activity-service-8748bcc7d-mxrjc",
 "ready": "0/1",
 "Status": "ImagePullBackOff",
 "restarts": 10,
 "age": "3h18m",
 "cpu": "12m",
 "memory": "287Mi"
}, {
 "name": "user-service-dxft89cc7d-mxrjc",
 "ready": "1/1",
 "Status": "Running",
 "restarts": 0,
 "age": "3h18m",
 "cpu": "42m",
 "memory": "1287Mi"
}]```